# Background-image overlayed with background-color in footer

Tags: html, css, footer

Is there any possibility to have background-image overlayed with background-color in footer?

```
<footer class="layout_footer">
...
</footer>

.layout_footer{
  background-image: url('./../images/footer.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` with your background image. I added `height:100px` just for demonstration.

Browsers will treat `linear-gradient` as an image and **will stack it with your actual image.**

```css
.layout_footer {

  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg');

  background-size: cover;

  height: 100px;

}
```

```html
<footer class="layout_footer">
  ...
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do with this **[:after](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)** css property

```css
.layout_footer{
  background-image: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b962594a4e8d0aa2219d0b5e15f72c39?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');
  background-size: cover;
position:relative;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
 }
.layout_footer:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<footer class="layout_footer"></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick :).

```
layout_footer {
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url('./../images/footer.jpg');
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately in this case all elements inside footer div become transparent too =) Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
.layout_footer{
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-image: url('./../images/footer.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);

}
```

Comment: Cool solution, but unfortunately not supported by ie

Answer (score 1):

This is from https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/

```
.tinted-image {
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(image.jpg);
}
```

Change the color and paths to your choice